# scanf - limit decimal places while reading

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I know how to limit the decimal and integer while printing values in printf (%x.x ),
In my scenario I want to implement that while reading from the console itslef.

So is there any way to llimit the number of decimals in a floating point value while reading using scanf function?

I tried below , doesn't show any errors while compiling but get's the value 0 always

```
float f1;
.
.
scanf("%.3f",&f1);
printf("%3.3f\n",f1);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you check the documentation, it says

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> A format specifier for scanf follows this prototype:
>
> `%[*][width][length]specifier`

and compare it to [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> A format specifier follows this prototype:
>
> `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`

You will see, there is no `precision` field in scanf. So i guess rounding (or casting to int to cut the digits) is the only way.

Comment: What does [*] in scanf and [flags] in printf mean?

Comment: Its in the links

Answer (score 0):

`f1 = round( f1 * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0`. `scanf` cannot help. BTW, use `double` instead of `float`.