# Trouble with entering doubles into an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on a c program that does not continue on when I enter a double when prompted. It skips and doesn't allow me to enter another number after the first run of the loop. Here is a sample of the code:

```
void total_max(double sale[], int n, double *total, double *max, int *max_id);

int main()
{
  int n = 7; // length of an array
  double sale[n];
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter the sales for salesperson %d\n", i+1);
    scanf("%.2f", &sale[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` can be used to read a line of input, then parse the line with `strtod`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 7; // length of an array
    double sale[n];
    char input[50] = "";
    char *next = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        do {
            printf("Enter the sales for salesperson %d\n", i+1);
            if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {//read up to 49 characters or up to newline
                sale[i] = strtod ( input, &next);
                if ( next == input) {//could not parse a double
                    *next = '\0';
                }
            }
            else {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets\n");
                return 0;
            }
        } while ( '\n' != *next);//repeat loop if next is not a newline
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {//print the doubles with precision of 2
        printf ( "%d %.2f\n", i + 1, sale[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but you should `#include <errno.h>`, assign the result of `strtod` to a temporary `double` and check `input != next` and validate `errno == 0` after the call to `strtod` to validate conversion before assigning `sale[i] = tmp_dbl;`. Otherwise, an inadvertent keystroke can result an undetected conversion failure.

Answer (score 0):

It skips because you are using precision field in format string. 
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29095617/9986735

> A format specifier for scanf follows this prototype:
>   **%[*][width][length]specifier** 
>   There is no precision field in scanf.

Just use: `scanf("%lf", &sale[i]);` instead.